# Load Balancer timeout annotation for GCE in service.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am creating a new Service of Type Load Balancer in google cloud.

As we can specify the connection idle timeout for AWS or azure by providing the annotation in metadata in service.yaml.

What is the similar annotation for the google cloud?

**service.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: "500"**

Comment: are you using GKE ingress?

Comment: No, I am creating a service of type Load Balancer in the kubernetes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is no possibility to configure the `idle connection timeout` for a service type of `LoadBalancer` in `GKE`.**

> Google Cloud external TCP/UDP Network Load Balancing (after this referred to as Network Load Balancing) is a regional, non-proxied load balancer.
>
> *[Cloud.google.com: External TCP/UDP LoadBalancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network)*

As said above, the network load balancer does not perform any type of modifications on the path as it's not a proxy but a forwarding rule. **It does not provide any timeout facility.**

If you are having issues with `idle connections` please check whole route that the traffic is taking to pinpoint where the issue could lie.

Please take a look on additional documentation:

- [Cloud.google.com: External TCP/UDP LoadBalancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network)
- [Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes engine: Services](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/service)
- [Kubernetes.io: Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)